# Chatterbot not setting the database name

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am trying to set the name for my database in chatterbot. Here is the code:-

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

def train_bot():
    chatbot = ChatBot('Bot',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    databse="mydb",
    trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer')
    for file in os.listdir('G:/Django Chatbot/SRC/chat_bot/data/'):
        convData = open(r'G:/Django Chatbot/SRC/chat_bot/data/' + file, encoding='UTF-8').readlines()
        chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
        chatbot.train(convData)
    print("Training completed")


train_bot()
```

I have referred to the documentation [here](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage/index.html#sql-storage-adapter). The sqlite3 database gets created with name 'db.sqlite3'. I want to change this name to be 'mydb.sqlite3' as specified in the code.

Comment: Your code raises **"AttributeError: 'ChatBot' object has no attribute 'set_trainer'"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you wrote `databse` instead of `database`

Comment: do i need to specify .sqlite3 as extension to the database name

Comment: i don't think so , the `.sqlite3` is added automatically.

Comment: This is not the right answer! Fixing the name 'databse' does not solve the problem. I use the nane 'database' correctly but the name I set is just ignored. The DB name is **always** the name stored in 'storage.py' of the ChatterBot library, which in my case it is **'db.sqlite3'**.

Comment: Also, the file extension '.sqlite3' is **not** added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I came in here quite late, but nevertheless the following may serve for other newcomers:

The spelling error ('databse') is not the problem. I was using it correctly and it was still ignored. The default DB name, in my case, is 'db.sqlite3'. It is set in 'storage.py' of the ChatterBot library, as `self.database_uri = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'`. So if you want to use another name, you have to do this:

```
chatbot = ChatBot('Bot',
storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
database_uri='sqlite:///mydb',
...
```

Note that there will be no file extension ('.sqlite3' or other) added to yhe filename you use. You have to add it yourself.